# is it possible to incept a class which being used by vendor's code in php?

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest

I'm using Laravel 5 framework.

I extended the `Illuminate\Http\Request` Class and added some functions. So I changed bootstrap to boot with my Custom Http Request Class. They work well.

But when it come to integrated test. by extending their TestCase, they use the Request class as below

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$request = Request::create();
```

Is there a way for me to override their class from using `Illuminate\Http\Request` to use `MyApp\Http\Request` at my own class? I don't want to change their code.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

Their code calls it directly, so there's unfortunately nothing you can do.